# the port freezes after a while and data do not show in the textboxes

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, serial-port, modbus

I am writing a Windows form program in which I read the temperature and the flux of a specific application by two sensors connected to an analogic input board. I need to read the values (every 1 second) constantly. the problem is that the program seems to freeze in texboxes after some minutes and the values in the textboxes freeze!
I first tried using System.threading.timer and System.timer, but then I tried defining new threads.is there any way like to reset the port or sth?
here is the code:

```
 public void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(changeflag));
        mainThread.Start();

        Thread checktempThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checkvalues));
        checktempThread.Start();

    }

  private void checkvalues()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (flag == true)
            {
                if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort.Open();
                }

                // Read analog values from input registers starting at address 33
                ushort startAddress = 33;

                ushort numRegistersToRead = 2;

                // Modbus slave device ID 
                byte slaveId = 49;


                // Read analog values from the input registers
                ushort[] analogValues = master.ReadInputRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegistersToRead);


                // Convert the ushort values to float and display them in the textboxes
                if (analogValues.Length >= 2)
                {
                    float temperatureValue = (float)analogValues[0];
                    float flussoValue = (float)(analogValues[1]);


                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        // We are not on the UI thread, so we need to use Invoke
                        Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxTemperatura.Text = temperatureValue.ToString()));
                        Invoke(new Action(() => textBoxFlusso.Text = flussoValue.ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // We are on the UI thread, so update the UI control directly
                        textBoxTemperatura.Text = temperatureValue.ToString();
                        textBoxFlusso.Text = flussoValue.ToString();
                    }
                }
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }


 private void changeflag()
    {
        while (rc1 == null)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1200);
            flag = true;
        
        }

    }
```

I tried timer, both in UI and use a thread, but it seems it makes the problem worse.

Comment: Instead of threads and loops, why not use [`SerialPort.DataReceived Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you need threads in this case. If you trying to read two registers every second it wouldn’t freeze your ui.
I had same issue with reading Modbus for long periods. I had int variable to increment every read (basically counter) and after it reaches specified value I would close the port and establish new connection.

Comment: thanks. my problem was exactly the same. it didn't freeze immediately but after a long period (minutes). I soleved the problem by using ReadInputRegistersAsync() method instead of ReadInputRegisters().

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I have to add more description to my problem: UI didn't freeze immediately but after a long period (minutes). I solved the problem by using `ReadInputRegistersAsync()` method instead of `ReadInputRegisters()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35323459)